# Delete function works on localhost but not on Web

Tags: php, slim

I made a function to delete an object in the database. When I test this function, It works on localhost, however, It doesn't work on the website. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?
P.S: I used Slim

```
$app->delete('/places/:id', 'authenticate', function($place_id) use($app) {
            global $user_id;

            $db = new DbHandler();
            $response = array();
            $result = $db->deletePlace($user_id, $place_id);
            if ($result) {
                $response["error"] = false;
                $response["message"] = "Place deleted succesfully";
            } else {

                $response["error"] = true;
                $response["message"] = "Place failed to delete. Please try again!";
            }
            echoRespnse(200, $response);
        });

public function deletePlace($user_id, $place_id) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("DELETE p FROM places p, user_places up WHERE p.id = ? AND up.place_id = p.id AND up.user_id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ii", $place_id, $user_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $num_affected_rows = $stmt->affected_rows;
        $stmt->close();
        return $num_affected_rows > 0;
    }
```

Comment: If it works in one place but not another. It's probably not the code. It's permissions or other environmental factors. The PHP error log will usually help figure out what's going on.

Comment: Look at your error logs.

Answer (score 0):

`DELETE p FROM places p` appears to be a syntax error in your SQL.

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare(
    "DELETE FROM places p, user_places up WHERE p.id = ? AND up.place_id = p.id AND up.user_id = ?"
);
```

To avoid missing these errors in the future, I'd suggest setting the error mode to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`:

```
$this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```